# Does this $ n^n >(n+1)^{n-1}$ hold for any real n, including negative and non-natural (rational, irrational)?

Tags: inequality

Does this  $ n^n >(n+1)^{n-1}$ hold for any real n, including negative and non-natural (rational, irrational)?

The case when $ n \geq 2$ is proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1556763/prove-inequality-by-induction-nn-n1n-1).

My guess is that it is true only for all natural $n>=2$.

Comment: No it doesn't because $n^n$ is not even defined for, say, $n=-\frac12$. The question is, however, an interesting one if you restrict $n$ to be strictly positive.

Comment: It is not true for $n = 1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we consider the $x\geq 0$, we can easily conclude that $$f(x)=x^x-(x+1)^{x-1}=0$$ for $x=0 \vee x=1$. Now, if $x\geq1$, the function $f(x)$ is an increasing functiuon, so it's always positive. When we set $x=\frac{1}{2}$, we have:
$$f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}-\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}<0$$
Also, you can't $x$ to be negative because if $x$ is in the form $-\frac{1}{2k}, k\in N_0$, the expression $x^x$ is not defined.

Now, we consider $x=-3$, we have:
$$f(-3)=-\frac{1}{27}-\frac{1}{16}=-\frac{43}{432}<0$$
So, if $x<0$ the function $f(x)$ isn't always positive.

Comment: @Code Complete: if this answer has been useful, maybe a $+1$?